# Read a variable that is placed inside my models file, in another file

Tags: python, django

In my models file I have this

```
class User(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            ('USER', (
                    (TYPE1, 'type 1'),
                    (TYPE2, 'type 2'),
                )
            ),
    ...
```

What I want to do is be able to access these values from my **forms.py** file, where I have

```
type = forms.CharField(label='Type', widget=forms.Select(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES))
```

As is of curse it will not work throwing

```
name 'USER_TYPE_CHOICES' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: add the name of the class in front of the attribute: `...forms.Select(choices=User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES))`

Comment: I swear I tried that and I got an error message. Now though its fine. I think it was just python trying to embarrass me. Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's usual scope rules still hold, so you need to add the name of the class in front of the attribute:

```
type = forms.CharField(label='Type', widget=forms.Select(choices=User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
from modul_contains_class_User import User
u = User(models.Model)
type = forms.CharField(label='Type', widget=forms.Select(choices = u.USER_TYPE_CHOICES))
```

Of course you have to replace `modul_contains_class_User` with the modul name where the `class User` has been defined.